# Are Flex/Flash Based applications susceptible to XSS attacks? what are the various ways in which such attacks can happen?

Tags: apache-flex, flash, security, xss

Are Flex/Flash based applications susceptible to XSS attacks,what are the different ways in which the attack can happen and how to prevent/detect such attacks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes.  They can be.  But it's not as common as with HTML/JavaScript.  Here is a good list of [XSS Vulnerabilities in Common SWFs](http://docs.google.com/View?docid=ajfxntc4dmsq_14dt57ssdw).